# Assigning different website user roles - asp.net IDENTITY

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I'm preparing my next week homework about asp.net IDENTITY. I managed to create an asp.net identity with Visual Studio 2013 on a website and make it up and running (using vb.net). I have all the tables created for the users, roles etc (connected to an SQL server), and authenticated parts on aspx pages. Everything works perfectly well. So far all the users have one role only.

The next step is to create different roles for diferent users (Editors and Commentators). The EDITORS will have the possibility to write articles, edit them and comment. The EDITORS will be added locally by the website administrator. They can't register on-line.  On the other hand, the COMMENTATORS will only have the possibility to discuss and comment (they can't write articles). Anyone can be registered as a commentator on-line.

How do I accomplish these roles and authenticate them? I've searched for documentation but no luck so far. Since asp.net Identity is a new framework I only found information here and there but nothing clear on how to implement website roles with the new Identity system. Or maybe I'm searching in the wrong place!!!

With this homework I am supposed to:
 1. assign the different roles (Editors and Commentators) in the database.
 2. to be able to athenticate the different roles in the Log In.
 3. to display contents on pages according to the user role.

Any documentation (step by step) about this would be highly appreciated. It's my first year of programming so please be patient with me LOL!!! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about AspNet.Identity is here:
http://www.asp.net/identity

The samples are excellent and are here: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks Sean....Interesting information but still nothing about my scenario. I've already gone through the basic information about the asp.net Identity.